# Need to update a new column in a table based on values from other columns

Tags: mysql

[image]I'm trying to update a new 'rubricscore' column based on the values in the other columns for every record.  That is, if a column has a certain string value, I will add 1 to the total, if it has a different value, I will add a 2. There are 3 possiblities for each column.  I need to do this for 5 columns.  Then, whatever the total value added up to be, I will update the new 'rubricscore' column with this value.  I have this so far:

```
SELECT id, @runtot AS rt,
CASE 
    WHEN classroommanagment = 'Self direction' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 1
    WHEN classroommanagment = 'Restating directions' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 2 
    WHEN classroommanagment = 'Moving' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 3
    WHEN teacherrole LIKE '%Mini lesson%' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 1
    WHEN teacherrole LIke '%Managing%' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 2 
    WHEN teacherrole LIKE '%Moving%' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 3
    and etc for the remaining three colomns

    END 
    FROM RUBERIC
```

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: HINT: `UPDATE`.  You want to update so you use `UPDATE`, not `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes, thanks Eric, since I'm still in the research/analysis phase... I didn't want to update any records yet.  While trying to formulate the query, I like to run 'selects' first to get close.

Comment: So, what is the problem ? As per your current query, it seems that you are in the right direction.

Comment: Hello Madhur, thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to 'loop' through each record so that I can tally a total (based on the other columns), and then insert (update) that total in the new rubricscore column.